# How to stream video in iOS app from GoPro HERO4?

Tags: udp, streaming, gopro

How to stream video in iOS app from GoPro HERO4? I am able to steam using GoPro HERO3. I have tried several ways but failed to stream.

Answer (score 0):

To start streaming you need to execute the URL:

http://10.5.5.9/gp/gpControl/execute?p1=gpStream&c1=start

To stop:

http://10.5.5.9/gp/gpControl/execute?p1=gpStream&c1=stop

Next you can download streaming data using port UDP 8554.
Unfortunately this solution working only with old software version. With last one 02.00.00 not working.

Comment: Do you need to connect the goPro to the IPhone wireless connection for that?Is there any way of getting the video while keeping a real connection to the internet?

Comment: Only if you have a data plan

Comment: You should turn on the wifi of the GoPro and use your iPhone to connect to it, at the same time you can connect your iPhone to the Internet with cellular data.